How to print multiple lines back to Wolfram from external C program?
I am developing a WSTP application using C and for debugging purposes, I am trying to print back multiple messages on to the kernel. This is what I have tried so far:
void sendMessage(char* message){
    WSPutFunction(stdlink, "EvaluatePacket", 1);
    WSPutFunction(stdlink, "Print", 1);
    WSPutString(stdlink, message);
    WSEndPacket(stdlink); 
    WSFlush(stdlink);
}

void testLog(){
    sendMessage("Hello");
    sendMessage("World");
    return;
}

The problem is that once the message gets printed, the link breaks:
In[346]:= TestLog[]                                                                                                    
Hello
World

LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link 
    LinkObject['/Users/sau/Developer/WSTP/logger', 2313, 49].

Out[346]= $Failed

What is the correct way to send data to the data for printing?
